# Firewalld: restrict ssh access to specific IP and allow that IP to access services in the interface zone

Tags: ssh, firewall, http, firewalld, source

The target setup is the following: I want to restrict ssh access to the server to a specific IP, and allow the http service to all. Now, to start from "scratch" I defined a new zone which I called "custom" and set it is as the default one. This is its current status:

```
custom (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0
  sources: 
  services: http
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

To allow only the 192.168.122.1 IP to access the SSH service I created another zone, which I called "limited-ssh":

```
limited-ssh (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 192.168.122.1
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

These interfaces are the only active ones:

```
custom
  interfaces: enp1s0
limited-ssh
  sources: 192.168.122.1
```

While this works, in the sense that only the specified IP is able to ssh into the machine, the same IP cannot access the http service. I guess it is because the "source" zone is processed before the "interface" zone. How can I restrict SSH access **AND** allow that IP to access the HTTP service (and all the other services in the "custom" zone)? Should I use a direct rule? I presume that if I add the http service to the limited-ssh zone it would work, but it would be repetitive and would quickly become a mess.

Comment: I wouldn't create a special zone for limited ssh. Just a zone public, private, and local. And then create a rule in the zones which allows ssh on a certain ip and denies everything else. In my opinion a zone is for defining a network segment, not for a specific service